# The imported package 'path' isn't a dependency of the importing package

Tags: flutter, dart

I just upgraded my packages and now I started seeing a warning:

[image]

What is causing this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One or some of your packages (mostly likely the [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/)) had [`path`](https://pub.dev/packages/path/) as transitive dependency before you upgraded to their latest version, so you were able to import `path` directly in your code.

But the latest version no longer has dependency on [`path`](https://pub.dev/packages/path/), so you will need to add this to your `pubspec.yaml` dependencies section like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  path: any
```

Comment: And to add to your answer: the active lint in OP's question is [`depend_on_referenced_packages`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/depend_on_referenced_packages.html)

Answer (score 14):

For me it was **moving package from dev_dependencies to dependencies.**

Manual import was working, but not suggestions and this warning was coming up.

Answer (score 12):

Or you can just reimport it. In my case the problem was here:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
```

So, I deleted import and add it back (**alt + Enter** for Android Studio):

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same warning, for me it was arriving only because the package that I was imported was not added directly in pubspec.yaml file although these packages were added in some of my custom packages' pubspec.yaml file, so instead of giving a error to firstly add it into my main pubspec.yaml file it was using it from some other custom packages that were connected to this project.

Comment: I had the same case exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this message because the **package** in which I was using the dependency **was not a dependency of the project**, and so when running pub get, the package's dependencies were never read.

In the **project level pubspec.yaml** I had not yet added my package:

```
dependencies:
  my_package:
    path: packages/my_package
```

Answer (score 0):

add your package under dependencies not under dev_dependencies: like,

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  abc : any <---- add here 

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  abc : any <---- not here
```

this solution works for me.
so, Try this hope this will help to reduce warning.