# How can I fix 'The imported package '' isn't a dependency of the importing package.' message on a project that uses a centralized dependency package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've been encountering the lint warning message in a project that imports a package that is responsible for maintaining dependencies:

> "The imported package 'get' isn't a dependency of the importing package."

The reason for this is that I didn't add the package directly on my project ***pubspec.yaml*** because I've created a package that receives all my dependencies so I can centralize changes on all the projects that depends on it.

The way I import the dependencies package for now is using path, as show in the examples.

Dependencies package ***pubspec.yaml*** example:

```
name: dependencies
description: dependencies of projects
version: 0.0.1
publish_to: 'none'

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  get: ^4.6.5
  logger: ^1.1.0
  device_info: ^2.0.0
  get_it: ^7.1.3
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
```

Main Project ***pubspec.yaml*** example:

```
name: main_project
description: main_project that depends on the package

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter 

dependency_overrides: 
  dependencies:
    path: packages/common/dependencies

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
```

I would like to know if there is any way that I can fix this lint warning message or should I just deactivate this message.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73910261/the-imported-package-path-isnt-a-dependency-of-the-importing-package) but I don't know if using `get: any` will try to search the latest version on pub.dev or it will recognize that I'm importing it from my depencies package manager.

Comment: what import is telling you that? perhaps get moved that kind of import to be transitive

Comment: @EdwynZN The import is import 'package:get/get.dart'; on my main_project. I don't think get.dart is transitive, because it works when I import the package directly on the main_project. For some reason, the message only appears when I try to use get from my main_project using the get dependency of the dependency manager. Btw this isn't exclusive only to the get dependency. Every dependency that comes from the dependency manager package is showing this error.

Comment: All the dependencies from your dependency manager package are transitive to main, thats why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your dependency manager package you should have a file in lib with the same name that your package `lib/dependencies.dart`, there you should export all your transitive dependencies that you want to expose and add an ignore message lint:

```
// ignore: invalid_export_of_internal_element
export 'package:get/get.dart';
.... //Same with all the packages you want to expose from this library
```

Comment: Guess this really is the only way huh. Thanks for the help